# 'RCTViewManager.h' file not found

Tags: facebook, react-native

I'm trying to implement Native UI Components https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html and when I try to create the following file in Xcode

```
// RCTMapManager.m
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTMapManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RCTMapManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[MKMapView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

I get the following error

> RCTMapManager.m:3:9: 'RCTViewManager.h' file not found

Then I tried to add the following path to the Header Search Path

> $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/**

The previous compilation error is gone but I get the following error when I run the project

> 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea ??

Comment: have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: @Zabojad Yes, please see the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem.

Basically there're two problems. First the import should be from "React/RCTViewManager.h" instead of "RCTViewManager".

Second, the class should not be named "RCTMapManager" as this class already exists. It should be named something else (e.g. "RNTMapManager").

Details could be found on the following github issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12404 and documentation was fixed with this pull request https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12523

Comment: Man, prefixing with `React`did it for me. Thank you so much!